# How to determine topic for a Kafka message

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have code like below to read from Kafka and save to Elasticsearch, I am using spark streaming:

```
JavaDStream<String> liness = messages.map(new Function<ConsumerRecord<String, String>, String>() {
        @Override
        public String call(ConsumerRecord<String, String> kafkaRecord) throws Exception {
            System.out.println(kafkaRecord.topic() + kafkaRecord.value());
            return kafkaRecord.value();
        }
    });

        JavaEsSparkStreaming.saveJsonToEs(lines, "events/redict");
        jssc.start();
```

My problem is that I need to make `"events/redict"` dynamic depending on the name of the topic, I also am able to fetch the topic name at `messages.map` call however how do I add the dynamism here?

Comment: What about mapping from the consumer record to a new object which consists of two fields, the String of the value and the value which depends on the topic?

Comment: Why are you not using Logstash, or Kafka Connect if all you want to do is save the Kakfa record to Elastic?

Comment: Thanks, cricket I am more comfortable with Spark.

Comment: Yes Dominik, that is a way to do it however was looking for a way where I din have to alter the mesage.

Comment: So you would rather program and deploy it to some type of Spark cluster then use tools built into either ELK stack or Kafka?

Comment: Yes I will deploy this to some server and fetch from there, actually use ES streaming to ingest, that is the plan so far. What say?

Comment: All I'm saying is that "writing fault-tolerant code" yourself should probably be avoided in favor of tools that do exactly what you're trying - https://www.confluent.io/blog/blogthe-simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-in-the-world-or-thereabouts-part-2/    & https://sematext.com/blog/kafka-connect-elasticsearch-how-to/

Comment: +1 to not reinventing the wheel. Kafka -> Elasticsearch is a solved problem, using Kafka Connect, and SMT, KSQL, or Kafka Streams if you want to do any transformations on the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would add "dynamism" here by either making one stream per topic, or filtering your `messages` stream into `events` and `redict` RDDs.

Individually, you save those two to the proper ES indicies.